# Not printing the statement after the if loop

Tags: python

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np
import requests 
from selenium import webdriver
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize,word_tokenize
print('ansife')
# html = requests.get('https://www.opentable.com/new-york-restaurant-listings')
# driver = webdriver.Firefox(,executable_path=r'[Your path]\geckodriver.exe')
html = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'D:\geckodriver.exe')
html.get("https://www.opentable.com/new-york-restaurant-listings")
counter = 0
lists = []
def parser_NYU(html):

    global counter,lists
    total_hotels_more_than_60_bookings = 0
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.page_source,'lxml')
    for i, restroom in enumerate(soup.find_all('div',class_='rest-row-info')):
        rest_name = restroom.find('span',class_='rest-row-name-text').text
        booking = restroom.find('div',class_='booking')  #.text
        words = list(word_tokenize(str(booking.text)))
        #same day

        if int(words[1]) > 100:
            print(booking.text)
            lists.extend([booking.text])

        print('listers',len(lists))
        print('this works fine')
        print('this works fine')    

    print('listers',len(lists))
    print('unfortunately this not works,why?')
    print('unfortunately this not works,why?')      

        
parser_NYU(html)
```

As you can see my print statements are not working after the if loop.
that is :

```
    print('listers',len(lists))
    print('this is not printing')  # not printing 
    print('this is not printing')
```

what did i messed up here?
what will be the main reason behind breaking the entire function after that if loop?
please help me, and advance thanks!

Comment: So, how can your code possibly print `"listers"` and not the next two lines?

Comment: I assume that your problem is that you are getting a lot of output (all the prints in the loop), but no the ones after? For me, `booking.text` does at some point throw an exception. Could it be that you just overlook the error message because the buffered prints happen afterwards? Please look at the full output for error messages.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrapers_soup.py", line 37, in <module>
    parser_NYU(html)
  File "scrapers_soup.py", line 21, in parser_NYU
    words = list(word_tokenize(str(booking.text)))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: could you please fix this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is two fault:

- The actual issues is that at some point `booking.text` fails because bs4 does not find a `div` with `class=booking`, so it returns `None`, which does not have the attribute `.text`, so an excpeion is thorwn. Just check if find returned `None`:

```
        rest_name = restroom.find('span',class_='rest-row-name-text').text
        booking = restroom.find('div',class_='booking')
        if booking is None:
            continue
        words = list(word_tokenize(str(booking.text)))
```

(best also do that for `rest_name`)

- The reason you are not seeing the error message is because it is hidden behind the wall of prints you are doing in the loop. Those are buffered, and might happen at a latter point, e.g. at application exit. However at application exit, the error message has already been printed (unbufferd) and the prints afterward hide them. Always check for errors.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to print the statements inside the if-condition (not if-loop) add the statements with proper indentation i.e. under the scope of if-condition.

```py
    for i, restroom in enumerate(soup.find_all('div',class_='rest-row-info')):
        rest_name = restroom.find('span',class_='rest-row-name-text').text
        booking = restroom.find('div',class_='booking')  #.text
        words = list(word_tokenize(str(booking.text)))
        #same day

        if int(words[1]) > 100:
#-----------Scope of if-block starts here--------#
            print(booking.text)
            lists.extend([booking.text])

            print('listers',len(lists))
            print('this is not printing')  # not printing 
            print('this is not printing')
#-----------Scope of if-block ends here--------#
```

If you mean to print it inside the for-loop and not if-condition, place the print statements under the scope of for-loop

```py
    for i, restroom in enumerate(soup.find_all('div',class_='rest-row-info')):
#-------Scope of for-block starts here--------#
        rest_name = restroom.find('span',class_='rest-row-name-text').text
        booking = restroom.find('div',class_='booking')  #.text
        words = list(word_tokenize(str(booking.text)))
        #same day

        if int(words[1]) > 100:

            print(booking.text)
            lists.extend([booking.text])

        print('listers',len(lists))
        print('this is not printing')  # not printing 
        print('this is not printing')
#-------Scope of for-block endshere--------#
```

Comment: yeah that works,but i dont want to print length of lists all the time, when it goes thru the loop, just once,but it seems that nothing is printing outside the if loop, why is that?

Comment: Did you check that the print statements are with proper indentation and inside the for-loop, in contrast to the code snippet mentioned in question, where the statements are outside the for-loop?

Comment: i edited the question, once more to get it more clear, could you please check that out ? i mean the code part.

Comment: Just like @quamrana commented, if you are able to print listeners, you should be able to print the statements that follow.

Comment: In that case it's possible that you are not escaping the for-loop itself.